# Trigger key press event on a text field

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a key press event using jquery on a text field for the enter key. I am currently doing it like this:

```
var key = jQuery.Event('keypress');
key.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
$('#txtb').trigger(key);
```

It triggers the event successfully on firefox but fails on Chrome and IE.

When I capture the key in the calling function it says undefined in Chrome but works fine in Mozilla.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

can you try this code

```
$('#txtb').trigger( "keypress", [13] );
```

Comment: Yo sup man, I haven't used this but if you can make a demo it will be good, looks good soltion if works, +1 to you as well! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) which JQuery normalizes it for cross-browser consistency:

> For key or mouse events, this property indicates the specific key or button that was pressed.

```
$('html').on('keyup', function(e){
   if (e.which == 13) { // if "enter" key is pressed
     var e = jQuery.Event("keypress", { keyCode: 64 }); // you can specify your desired key code 
     $('#txtb').trigger(e); // or $('#txtb').trigger("keypress")
   }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gJwrM/1/)

Comment: + 1 and late good night bruver, I would recommend elaborate on `triggerHandler` :)

Comment: @Tats_innit thanks, good night bro, I live in Iran. it's 17 o'clock :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but keyCode or which both are not working for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do this way:-

```
$('#txtb').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      alert('Handler for .keydown() called.');
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/bcnUf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works for triggering specific keyboard key presses.

```
var e = $.Event("keypress"); /* || keydown || keyup */
e.which = 65; /* set the key code here */
$(selector).trigger(e);
```